# Use foreach to perform action for each of the fields (of the same type) defined in a class?

Tags: c#, foreach

For example, is it possible to use a foreach statement to perform an action for each string in a class?

```
foreach (string s in <class>)
```

like I can use it with AppSettings?

```
foreach (string key in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings)
```

If it isn't possible, is there any other similar way to do so?

Comment: Please explain 'each string in a class'.

Comment: Coming from Javascript?  The answer is yes and no and I doubt you want to do it that way.

Comment: [How to make a  C# class usable in a foreach statement](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322022/en-us)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the namespaces `System.Reflection` and `System.Linq`

```
foreach (var pi in typeof(<YourClass>).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string))))
{
    pi.SetValue(targetObject, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) will iterate over any class that implements `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`.  So yes, if your class implements `IEnumerable` and can return a collection of strings then you can use `foreach`.

Keep in mind that the strings in `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` are not *properties*.  There's no built in way to enumerate of the the properties of a class.  One way would be to iterate over the classes properties using [`Type.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperties.aspx) looking for any properties of a given type (`string' in your example).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if given class implements `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` (`T` is `string` in your case). Refer to [How to: Access a Collection Class with foreach (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb8xew9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [How to: Create an Iterator Block for a Generic List (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee5kxzk0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ttw7t8t6.aspx) iterate any implementation of [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) or [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9eekhta0.aspx) interfaces. So it is possible if your class implements one of these interfaces.

[`ConfigurationManager.AppSetting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) is a property. It values types is [`NameValueCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) class. And it inherited from [`NameObjectCollectionBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase.aspx) class. And `NameObjectCollectionBase` implements `IEnumerable` interface.

Check out these;

- [How to read a key from app setting file when value is know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330570/how-to-read-a-key-from-app-setting-file-when-value-is-know)
- [Getting a StringCollection out of AppSettings through the configuration manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235784/getting-a-stringcollection-out-of-appsettings-through-the-configuration-manager)
- [How to make a C# class usable in a foreach statement](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322022/en-us)

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand a little more of foreach loops now.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public  class TestClass {
        public string String1 { get; set; }
        public string String2 { get; set; }
        public int Int1 { get; set; }


        public TestClass() {
            String1 = "Frank";
            String2 = "Borland";
            foreach (var item in this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(string)))) {
                string value = item.GetValue(this, null) as string;
                Debug.WriteLine("String: {0} Value: {1}", item.Name, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Prints out the Names and Values of your class instance strings.